# Dictionary with Nested Lists to Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I currently have a dictionary with some nested lists that's a bit messy:

`table = {"name":"ClosestDefender10ftPlusShooting",
"headers":["PLAYER_ID","PLAYER_NAME_LAST_FIRST","SORT_ORDER","GP","G",
"CLOSE_DEF_DIST_RANGE","FGA_FREQUENCY","FGM","FGA","FG_PCT","EFG_PCT","FG2A_FREQUENCY","FG2M","FG2A","FG2_PCT","FG3A_FREQUENCY","FG3M","FG3A","FG3_PCT"],
"rowSet":[[2544,"James, LeBron",1,6,2,"0-2 Feet - Very Tight",0.014,0,0.33,0,0,0.007,0,0.17,0,0.007,0,0.17,0],[2544,"James, LeBron",2,6,6,"2-4 Feet - Tight",0.144,0.83,3.5,0.238,0.31,0.082,0.33,2,0.167,0.062,0.5,1.5,0.333],[2544,"James, LeBron",3,6,5,"4-6 Feet - Open",0.192,2.17,4.67,0.464,0.571,0.103,1.17,2.5,0.467,0.089,1,2.17,0.462],[2544,"James, LeBron",4,6,6,"6+ Feet - Wide Open",0.11,1.33,2.67,0.5,0.656,0.041,0.5,1,0.5,0.068,0.83,1.67,0.5]]}`

and using pandas I'd like to get it into a table where my headers are all values in the `headers` list, and the each row is named after the values in `rowSet`, like the tables shown here: http://stats.nba.com/player/2544/shots-dash/?sort=G&dir=-1

I've tried a few things like `df = pd.DataFrame(list(table.items()))` and things of that nature but they all return pretty scrambled tables, and so I'm not sure how to deal with the nested nature of this dictionary.

The rest of the code is:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/playerdashptshots?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=6&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=2544&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Playoffs&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision='

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
table = response.json()['resultSets'][5]
data_headers = table.get('headers')
```

is there any way to do this in a few lines, or do I need to go down a more manual route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=table['rowSet'], columns=table['headers'])
```

output:

```
   PLAYER_ID PLAYER_NAME_LAST_FIRST  SORT_ORDER  GP  G   CLOSE_DEF_DIST_RANGE  \
0       2544          James, LeBron           1   6  2  0-2 Feet - Very Tight   
1       2544          James, LeBron           2   6  6       2-4 Feet - Tight   
2       2544          James, LeBron           3   6  5        4-6 Feet - Open   
3       2544          James, LeBron           4   6  6    6+ Feet - Wide Open   

   FGA_FREQUENCY   FGM   FGA  FG_PCT  EFG_PCT  FG2A_FREQUENCY  FG2M  FG2A  \
0          0.014  0.00  0.33   0.000    0.000           0.007  0.00  0.17   
1          0.144  0.83  3.50   0.238    0.310           0.082  0.33  2.00   
2          0.192  2.17  4.67   0.464    0.571           0.103  1.17  2.50   
3          0.110  1.33  2.67   0.500    0.656           0.041  0.50  1.00   

   FG2_PCT  FG3A_FREQUENCY  FG3M  FG3A  FG3_PCT  
0    0.000           0.007  0.00  0.17    0.000  
1    0.167           0.062  0.50  1.50    0.333  
2    0.467           0.089  1.00  2.17    0.462  
3    0.500           0.068  0.83  1.67    0.500
```